# Error while installing Couchbase Sync Gateway

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am trying to install Sync Gate way , (Windows 8,64 bit)
but it is showing some error (attached image file please have a look over it)...does any one know how to resolve this error ? please help me out...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ2kY.png)

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/1573) on the sync_gateway github repo covers the issue. In particular this comment has a workaround:

> Quick note for those looking for a workaround
>
> Run a command prompt as Administrator and enter the following command
>   to install Sync Gateway as a service after installing Sync Gateway via
>   the clean install/non-upgrade path explained above:
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Couchbase\sg-windows.exe" install "c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Couchbase\sync_gateway.exe" "c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Couchbase\serviceconfig.json" from there you can run the
>   following command to actually start the service:
>
> net start SyncGateway